# How to disable autorun referenced services

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I've project which has references to some services. Everytime when i'd like to debug this project all referenced services start. Is there any way to disable those services and run them onle when they are necessary? Sometimes while debuging i'm not using data form webServices and it takes too much time to start them all and check some minor features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are separate projects, you can disable those projects. Right click on the project in the solution explorer and pick "Disable".